# Jenkins: Taking a machine offline if a certain test fails

Tags: jenkins

I am aware of plugins that will take a machine offline if a build fails. My question is that can I take a machine offline if a certain step fails?

I'm running certain windows batch pre-build steps that revert each machine and want to take a slave offline if the revert fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange requirement, but I respect it :)

Brut force - If you want to take the slave out, you can just kill it (kill the java process) from a batch file running on that slave. Use taskkill (run **taskkill /?** on command line to see usage) in a batch file, which you should fork within the job using the **start** command (see **start /?** on command line to see usage).

Also, look at [this](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Monitor+and+Restart+Offline+Slaves) and [this post](http://jenkins.361315.n4.nabble.com/Offline-and-revert-slave-after-build-td4631215.html). Looks like a similar need to yours with a nicer control.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Not very elegant, but should do the job!

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but here are some other approaches I have considered (and tried). We have a job that monitors the build machines and invokes Pager Duty if a slave goes offline or runs low on disk space. Forcibly taking the machine offline is problematic in our environment.

1. Rather than remove the slave (e.g. kill it or take it offline) you can change the label on the machine so that other jobs will no longer select it. This can be done with groovy. **CAVEAT: label changes seem to take a while to propagate** so the machine may still be selected.
2. Use the [Conditional Build Step](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin) plugin and upon failure use groovy to take the machine offline. NOTE: I haven't tested this groovy... it is old.

   ```
     manager.build.getBuiltOn().toComputer.setTemporarilyOffline(true)
   ```
3. Rather than take the machine offline, you could make that job run forever (sleep, sleep, sleep) - it will not be offline, but it won't be available any longer for other jobs to select it. In the meanwhile, it could keep retrying recovery.
4. There is also a [Node Stalker](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Node+Stalker+Plugin) plugin that will allow a downstream job to run on the SAME node as an upstream job. That way when the failure occurs, your downstream job can do the cleanup. There is a slight risk that another job scheduled for the failed machine gets in first, however.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to take machines offline only from command prompt? Else you can use groovy post build step to write simple script to take each machine offline. From command prompt, you will not have access to other slaves unless you use some power shell utilities.